# How to program a loop in python that sums numbers

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I am trying to write a loop that calculates the total of the following series of numbers: 1/30 +2/29+3/28+…+30/1.
I'm having trouble figuring out how to add, because the program below just displays the total as 0.033333333....

```
def main():
  A=1
  B=30
  sum=(A/B)
  while A<=30:
      A+=1
      B-=1
  print('Total:',sum)
main()
```

Comment: To compute the exact sum directly: `f = sum(fractions.Fraction(i, 31-i) for i in range(1, 31)); print(f, float(f))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not adding anything to `sum` on each iteration. You must add

```
sum = sum + A / B
```

inside the `while` loop. But you have to initialize `sum` with zero:

```
sum = 0
```

**Note:**

Don't use `sum` as name of a variable because it's a built-in function of Python. You can call that variable `result`, `my_sum`, ...

**Code:**

```
def main():
    A = 1
    B = 30
    result = 0
    while A <= 30:
        print A, B
        result += (A / B)
        A += 1
        B -= 1

    print('Total:', result)
main()
```

**Also:**

You can see that in each term of the sum, `A + B == 31`, so `B == 31 - A`. Therefore, the code can be simplified:

```
def main():
    A = 1
    result = 0
    while A <= 30:
        result += (float(A) / (30 - A + 1))
        A += 1
    print('Total:', result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create two lists of the desired numbers, compute the value of each fraction, then sum then.

`sum(( a/b for a,b in zip(range(1,31),range(30,0,-1))))`

Comment: Since he said he got `0.0333...`, he must be using Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

You may mean this to be your code:

```
def main():
    A=1
    B=30
    sume= A/B
    while B>1:
        A+=1
        B-=1
        sume += A/B
    print('Total:',sume)

main()
```

Moreover, you shouldn't override `sum` unless you know you are not using it in your program elsewhere. `sum` is a reserved word in python.

Answer (score 0):

total = 0.0

for x in range(1, 31, 1):

```
z = x / (31-x)

total += z
```

print(f'The total is {total:.2f}.')

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.